# android e book from html

Tags: android

I want to develope an e book for android. My data is in internet but not a json or a xml only html page. the data changes often. so data must be update often and must be saved on phone so people can read without internet.How can I parse data from html? can I convert the page json?can you suggest me some ways or methods?Must I use sqllite or save the page sd card?

data page= http://www.mevzuat.adalet.gov.tr/html/388.html

Comment: I would simply download the page to the SD card for offline viewing and whenever the user opens the app and there is a network connection, re-download it/check to see if there is a newer version

Answer (score 2):

Store it as plain File, use basic HTTP codes to indicate updates with regular polling using AlarmManager, and display it in a WebView.

Basically, you don't need to parse anything if your html page is formatted for a proper mobile display.

Comment: page is not suitable for mobile devices so I want to parse data.and develope my own application. it is a government page so I can not reach the database.

Comment: it will be 100 times easier to adapt your html to have a proper rendering than to parse it and redisplay it again. Or, you could store it in a storage format, such as anything but not html (xml, json, whatever...)